# What's the best and efficient choice between 'T', 'K' and Regular Intel Processors

Tags: cpu

What is the best choice when selecting intel processors considering its specs and performance with hardcore usage.

The options are:

- 'K' Unlocked Processor
- 'T' Power-optimized lifestyle
- and the Regular one

Their differences only varies with their GHz and wattage.

I can't decide or know what exactly matters between those specs, what's the up and down. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "K" series is unlocked therefore allows for more overclocking, which would be optimal for "hardcore" usage. If you do not overclock, it would have the same performance as the non-K, regular one.

For the power optimized series, refer to online benchmarks that compare its performance to regular one.